# my jquery code is not working when I remove alert from my m2e.i18nLocalizePage() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internationalization

I have the following javascript code.

```
function getLanguage() {
    // Add any variations of a language value and map to a supported language.
    var langMap = {
        /*German/Deutsch */
        "de": "de",
        "de-at": "de",
        "de-de": "de",
        "de-li": "de",
        "de-lu": "de",
        "de-ch": "de",
        /*English*/
        "en": "en-us",
        "en-gb": "en-gb",
        "en-us": "en-us",
        /*French*/
        "fr": "fr-fr",
        "fr-fr": "fr-fr",
        "fr-be": "fr-fr",
        "fr-ca": "fr-fr",
        "fr-lu": "fr-fr",
        "fr-ch": "fr-fr",
        /*Italian*/
        "it": "it",
        "it-it": "it",
        "it-ch": "it"
    };

    //         Querystring parameter         Mozilla               IE
    var lang = getParameterByName("lang") || navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

    // Default to en-us
    return (lang && langMap[lang.toLowerCase()]) ? langMap[lang.toLowerCase()] : langMap["en"];
}

// Public Functions
m2e.i18nGetString = function (id) {
    return m2e.i18n[id] || ("" + id + ": String not found.");
};

m2e.i18nFormat = function () {
    var argLen = arguments.length;
    var str = m2e.i18nGetString(arguments[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i < argLen; i++) {
        var pattern = "\\{" + (i - 1) + "\\}";
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(pattern, "g"), arguments[i]);
    }
    return str;
};

m2e.i18nLocalizePage = function (context) {
    if (m2e.i18n) {
        //alert("testing");
        context = context ? context : "*";
        $.each($('[data-i18n]', $(context)), function (index, item) {
            id = $(item).attr("data-i18n") || "EMPTY_data-i18n";
            id = id.split(";")[0];
            val = m2e.i18nGetString(id);
            if (isTagName(item, 'input') || isTagName(item, 'textarea')) {
                // Handle placeholder
                $(item).attr('placeholder', val);
            } else if (isTagName(item, 'img')) {
                // Handle alt text
                $(item).attr('alt', val);
            } else {
                // Handle HTML contents
                $(item).html(val);
            }
        });
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: "../../App/js/i18n/i18n_" + getLanguage() + ".js",
    dataType: "script",
    async: false
});
```

Whenever I keep and alert in m2e.i18nLocalizePage() function it works perfectly. but when I removed the alert from the same function it is not working at all.
I tried searching on net and everywhere it is written it is a timing issue because of ajax asynchronous call but in the code I've kept ajax async as false but still it is not working.
help me.

Comment: What is your ajax call doing exactly and where is `m2e.i18nLocalizePage` being invoked? You may need to break down your code here further.

Comment: Instead of attempting to make synchronous Ajax call (which seems not to work) maybe you should call localize page in Ajax callback?